# An inequality involving quadratic integers

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

Let $d$ be a positive integer which is not the square of any integer, $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ and $u:=x+y \sqrt d$

$u$ is such that $$ u \geq 1 \;\text{and} \; |u \overline u|=|(x+y \sqrt d)(x-y \sqrt d)|=|x^2-dy^2|=1  $$

Prove that $$x\geq 1 \; \text{and} \; y \geq 0$$

So far, I've tried case working (whether $x^2-dy^2=1$ or $x^2-dy^2=-1$)

Thanks for your help, especially if you got a more straightforward approach.

Comment: Since $(-u)(\overline{-u}) = u\overline{u}$, you can't prove $x \geq 1$ and $y\geq 0$ from $\lvert x^2-dy^2\rvert = 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot an important condition : $u \geq 1$. Note that I've finished case 1. Things aren't going as fine with case 2 though.

Comment: You probably require $d>1$, otherwise we could have $x=0, y=1, d=1, u=1$.

Comment: right, I thought the "squarefree" phrase had the meaning "which is not the square of any integer". So yes, $d \geq 2 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we must exclude $d = 1$, apart from the fact that then the representation $u = x+y\sqrt{1}$ is not unique, we can also write $0^2 - 1\cdot 1^2 = -1$, and the condition $x \geqslant 1$ is not met.

For $d > 1$, if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign (where $0$ has the same sign as any integer), $x + y\sqrt{d} \geqslant 1$ clearly requires $x,y$ non-negative, and since for $y \neq 0$ we have $-dy^2 \leqslant -d < -1$, it is clear that we also must have $x \neq 0$, whence $x \geqslant 1$.

So it remains to see that $x$ and $y$ can't have opposite signs. Let $u = x + y\sqrt{d}$ with $xy < 0$ and $\lvert x^2-dy^2\rvert = 1$. Then

$$\lvert x+y\sqrt{d}\rvert = \left\lvert (x+y\sqrt{d})\frac{x-y\sqrt{d}}{x-y\sqrt{d}}\right\rvert = \frac{1}{\lvert x-y\sqrt{d}\rvert} = \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert\sqrt{d}} < 1.$$

So that can't happen.

Comment: This is a nice proof! How did you get the idea of checking $x$ and $y$ signs ?  Moreover, I find it very astute that $xy<0$ implies $|x-y \sqrt d| = |x|+|y| \sqrt d $ !

Comment: Many many moons ago, I solved a similar exercise. The method stuck in memory.